# Calling a method with Generic signature and parameter

Tags: c#

I have the following signature which has a generic type and parameter as below:

```
List<T> GetMyList<T>(T filter);
```

The filter type is different from the list type. I am trying to call like this:

```
var myList = repo.GetMyList<List<items>>(filter);
```

I am not sure how to specify the type of 'filter' in the method call. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean? Whatever type you pass into your method will define it for the method, so you can just call `repo.GetMyList(filter)`, and the `T` will be whatever type your `filter` parameter is.

Comment: You can't - the function takes in a filter of type `T` and returns a list of type `T`.  There's no way around that.  Maybe if you explained the problem in more detail a solution could be determined, but what you are asking is not possible with that signature.

Comment: Are you in control of `List<T> GetMyList<T>(T filter);`? Meaning can you change it's signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the types are different, you need to have 2 generic types, like below:

```
public List<T1> GetMyList<T1, T2>(T2 filter);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked and to call it I used `var myList = repo.GetMyList<items, string>(filter);`